# Session or LocalStorage CRUD table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a CRUD webpage using angularjs and localstorage. The add, edit and delete functions all work perfectly well. I was able to use localstorage and save data after adding or deleting a user.

But i am unable to save edited user details on localstorage. They get erased on refresh of the webpage. The **$scope.selectUser** is the function I use to edit a user. Thanks in advance.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
    console.log("in controller...");
    $scope.newUser = {};
    $scope.info = "";

    if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
        $scope.users = [
            { email: "John@yahoo.com", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", contact: "281-283-2480", role: "Supplier-Admin", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Rick@yahoo.com", firstName: "Rick", lastName: "Fraiser", contact: "987-283-2489", role: "Supplier-User", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Sam@yahoo.com", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Tarly", contact: "456-786-2480", role: "BuyerAdmin", company: "Samsung" }
        ];
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    } else {
        $scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }


    $scope.saveUser = function () { 
        console.log("Saving...");
        $scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
        $scope.info = "New User Added Successfully!";
        $scope.newUser = {};
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        //localStorage.setItem("email", $scope.users);
    };

    $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
        $scope.clickedUser = user;
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    };

    $scope.deleteUser = function () {
        console.log($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser));
        $scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser), 1);
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        $scope.info = "User Deleted Successfully!";
        
    };        

    $scope.clearInfo = function () {
        $scope.info = "";
    };
});
```

Comment: local and session storage provide fairly simple API's (`getItem`, `setItem`, etc). What specifically do you need assistance with?

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to implement session or local storage. However, I would highly suggest using a library for this. One I've used I'll link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngstorage)

Comment: @FrankModica When I add, delete or edit a user, they should not be erased when I refresh the web page or move to another page and coming back again. To do that, I need to use the localstorage or sessionstorage. I just don't know where and how to implement them.

Comment: @Mickers Yes. I haven't implemented session or local storage as I don't know where and how to write them. I'm looking for some guidance.

Comment: @VaibhavShankar They're part of the global object. You just have to do things like `localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify($scope.users))` and then the opposite to get them out of storage, like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))`

Comment: @FrankModica Thanks for the reply. I tried them out. Doesn't work :(. I deleted a user and when I refreshed the page, it came back. I have updated the code in the question. Please check the code up there.

Comment: you never deleted them out of the storagethough, you are splicing the variable user. you should try to use localStorage.removeItem() to delete, or edit the localStorage by using localStorage.getItem() and edit that result

Comment: It seems like you just placed `localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify($scope.users));` randomly in the controller. Why would you expect that to work? You need to do that whenever the items need to be saved.

Comment: @FrankModica So where do I place the setItem code? Putting them in the $scope.deleteUser function also doesn't work when I delete a user.

Comment: Also, just doing `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));` won't work. You need to assign that to `$scope.users`.

Comment: I think you should start simple by putting the `localStorage.setItem` code inside your `saveUser` method. Then try to get the value from local storage and see if it worked. Take it from there.

Comment: @FrankModica Frankly, I have no idea where to place the code. Can you please tell me where and what code i should put? I'm still learning to code.

Comment: @FrankModica Hey. I have somehow managed to use localstorage for add and delete function. But I am unable to fix the edit button.

Comment: Hey I don't see much implementation in that function - what's not working?

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for help. I somehow figured it out and now i am able to get the edit function working :). My question is solved.